# Powershell missing array after conversion

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, object

When I convert a powershell object, the array at property `bar` and property `foo` is missing. I use the following command to export the generated json object to a file: `$stackoverflow| ConvertTo-Json | set-content '.\foobar.json'`

```
@stackoverflow = @{
    name = "question"
    description = "stackoverflow is amazing!"
    version = 1.0
    myattribute = @(
        @{
            foo = @("value1")
            bar = @("value2")
        }
    )
}
```

I expect the output should look like this `foo = ["value1"]` and `bar = ["value2]`, but the actual output in the json file is `foo = "value1"` and `bar = "value2"`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: ```-Depth 42```

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for the hint! This did it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work as you expected by quoting the version number and removing the splat from myattribute:

```
$stackoverflow = @{
    name = "question"
    description = "stackoverflow is amazing!"
    version = "1.0"
    myattribute = (
        @{
            foo = @("value1")
            bar = @("value2")
        }
    )
}
```

The output from `$stackoverflow | ConvertTo-Json`

```
{
    "myattribute":  {
                        "bar":  [
                                    "value2"
                                ],
                        "foo":  [
                                    "value1"
                                ]
                    },
    "description":  "stackoverflow is amazing!",
    "name":  "question",
    "version":  "1.0"
}
```

Comment: But then, the array of `myattribute` is also gone. The `-Depth` parameter did the trick.